# How to convert Datepicker Date using PHP strtotime & date function?

Tags: php, datepicker

I am using datePicker for date selection in the front end. I have shown date like this:

```
September,30 2012
```

But when I receive it in PHP and try to convert it into date format, it generates wrong date.

```
$var = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('September,30 2012'));
```

The above gives me 1970/01/01.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `,` from the datepicker's output..And it'll be fine

```
$var = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('September 30 2012'));
```

gives you 2012-09-30

And to remove comma,use

```
$daf = 'September 30 2012';
echo str_replace(',','',$daf); // gives September 30 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
 $var = date('F d y', strtotime('September 30 2012'));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its the comma that is doing that... removing comma gives u correct answer..
try this

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('September 30 2012'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the comma and you get the solution

```
<?php
    $date = 'September,30 2012';
echo $var = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('September-30-2012')); //this gave me 1970/01/01
```

or just remove the dash it works in both scenario

[**Here is the working solution**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/67PVTE)